# Worksheet_Change compare values to list

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use worksheet_change as a data validation check. I want to insure values pasted into cells range a1:a3000 match a list of values from a list. I'm afraid I'm lost and don't know how to proceed.

Here is what I have so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rang As Range
Set Rang = Worksheets("DATA INPUT SHEET").Range("A1:A3000")
    If Intersect(Target, Rang) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

What I want to add would be along the lines of:

```
If Target.Value <> Worksheets("Worksheet 2".Range("B2:B7") Then
MsgBox "The value you entered is not valid"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add this:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(target.value, Worksheets("Worksheet 2").Range("B2:B7"), 0)) Then
    MsgBox "The value you entered is not valid"
End If
```

where you want in the code.

Comment: Hi Scott,  this worked well. I needed to remove the "not" in the first line. Otherwise it was giving me an error if it WAS on the list.

And forgive me for not phrasing my question clearly, but this works on single cells. What I really need is one which will reject if multiple values are pasted into Column A, say 1-1000. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I actually noticed that myself, If you look at the edit I did an hour ago I had removed it.  Please consider marking as correct.

Comment: Yes Scott! You were definitely correct. I had not refreshed my page. My mistake!

Comment: You will need to loop through the Target range and test each one. @MatthewIngle