# EXCEL, VBA formula to check if data in cell is one or more item from the list

Tags: excel, vba, list, contains

I am currently writing a code in VBA to check if user input correct data in spreadsheet and I am stuck on one check.

Cell must be filled with values from the list, can be one value or multiple values separated by comma.

List contains: EQ/FI/RE/PF/FX/ED/OD

correct input examples:
`EQ`, `FX`, `FI, PF`, `EQ, FI, PF, ED, OD` etc.
inncorect input examples: `anything not from the list`

How can I write this code in VBA?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us the code you wrote in VBA?

Comment: The thing is i don't know where to start with this. I was thinking about Wildcards and Like statement but it didn't get me anywhere. I don't want to be rude and ask for completed code, I just want some ideas where to start and search.

Comment: You may not need the VBA. You can do this with [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249)

Comment: I already have VBA code that checks and marks with color cells that don't match specific conditions (date format, specific format based and adjacent cell etc.). Data validation is not helpful here.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you pick up the approach [Worksheet_Change compare values to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622978/worksheet-change-compare-values-to-list)

Comment: I don't know if you understand me correct. Every solution that you provided would require me to prepare a list of every possible combination there is. Because in single cell I want to check there can be one or multiple combinations of data from the list.

Comment: Sounds like you need to break the contents of the tested cell into individual parts (comma separated) using `SPLIT` and then test each one against the list using `FOR EACH... ...NEXT` loop. Depending on how you're storing your list - as a table on sheet or hard coded into your code etc. will define how you do each test.

Answer (score 0):

I used split option and this is the working code I came with

```
Function listCheck(listStrng As String) As Boolean
Dim listArr, items As Variant
Dim i, x As Long
x = 0
arritems = Array("a", "b", "c") 'hard coded list
listArr = Split(listStrng, ", ")
For i = LBound(listArr) To UBound(listArr) 'loop through each item on the list and check if it's on hard coded list
    If IsError(Application.Match(listArr(i), arritems, 0)) Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
If x > 0 Then
    listCheck = False
    Else
    listCheck = True
End If
End Function

Sub test123()
Dim dane As String
    dane = Range("a1").Value
    tekst = listCheck(dane)
    MsgBox (tekst)
End Sub
```

I hope someone will find it helpful in the future.